# Send data from service and getting cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm getting the data from service layer (not managed).

**BUT**

My code:

```
//Parent
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true)
private Collection<Child> childCollection;

//Child
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_PARENT", referencedColumnName = "ID_PARENT")
private Parent parent;
```

Ps.: I'm doing the **bidirectional** link

When I do the merge I'm getting:

A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: : my.system.model.vo.Parent.childCollection

I want to do the automatic merge... I don't wanna the manual way like:

```
find(parent);
parent.child.clear();
flush();
```

Thanks!!